# Why is an instance value resetting after each update

Tags: python

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.check = [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]

    def test(self,x):
        self.check[x]=True
        print(self.check)

test().test(5)
test().test(4)
test().test(3)
test().test(1)
print("|----------------------------------------------------------------------|")
print(test().check)
```

Why it doesn't print out:

```
[False,True,False,True,True,True,False,False]
```

And it instead prints the initial:

[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]

Comment: The beginning of each line, `test().` creates a new instance on each line.  Create a single new instance (e.g. `t = test()`) and use that (`t.test(5); t.test(4); ...`)

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure since your indentation is messed up, but `check` appears to be an *instance attribute* - each of the five instances of `test` that you created has its own version of the attribute.  To make it a *class attribute* instead, it would have to be assigned in the class body, outside of any method.

Comment: you are creating new instance  in every line and they are not related to each other

Answer (score 2):

You are not saving the instance in a variable, you are creating five different instances:

```
test_instance = test()
test_instance.test(5)
test_instance.test(4)
....
```